# Function to create nested dictionary from lists

Tags: python

I am tasked with the following question, but cannot come up with the right code:

This exercise involves building a non-trivial dictionary.The subject is books.

The key for each book is its title
The value associated with that key is a dictionary

In that dictionary there will be Three keys: They are all strings, they are:
`"Pages", "Author", "Publisher"`

`"Pages"` is associated with one value - an `int`
`"Author"` is associated with a dictionary as value
That `"Author"` dictionary has two keys: `"First"`, and `"Last"` each with a string value
`"Publisher"` is associated with a dictionary as value
That `"Publisher"` dict has one key `"Location"` with a string as value.

An Example might look like:

```
{"Harry Potter": {"Pages":200, "Author":{"First":"J.K", "Last":"Rowling"}, "Publisher":{"Location":"NYC"}},
"Fear and Lothing in Las Vegas": { ...}}
```

Code a function called `"build_book_dict"`
ACCEPT five inputs, all lists of n-length
A list of titles, pages, first, last, and location.

RETURN a dictionary as described above.
Keys must be spelled just as they appear above - correctly and capitalized.

---

Here is an example:

```
titles = ["Harry Potter", "Fear and Lothing in Las Vegas"]
pages = [200, 350]
firsts = ["J.K.", "Hunter"]
lasts = ["Rowling", "Thompson"]
locations = ["NYC", "Aspen"]

book_dict = build_book_dict(titles, pages, firsts, lasts, locations)
print(book_dict)
```

---

```
{'Fear and Lothing in Las Vegas': {'Publisher': {'Location': 'Aspen'}, 'Author': {'Last': 'Thompson', 'First': 'Hunter'}, 'Pages': 350} 'Harry Potter': {'Publisher': {'Location': 'NYC'},'Author': {'Last': 'Rowling', 'First': 'J.K.'}, 'Pages': 200}}
```

---

My code currently looks the following:

```
def build_book_dict(titles, pages, firsts, lasts, locations):
    inputs = zip(titles, pages, firsts, lasts, locations)
    for titles, pages, firsts, lasts, locations in inputs:
        dict = {
            titles : {
                "Pages" : pages,
                "Author" : {
                    "First" : first,
                    "Last" : last
                            },
                "Publisher" : {
                    "Location" : locations
                                },
                        },
                }

    return dict
```

But it only stores the information of the last "book".

Comment: Why did you expect otherwise? You only return a single dictionary. Also don't shadow the built-in `dict`.

Comment: I think it is natural because you defined `dict` in `build_book_dict` such as you want, not append to list or something.

Comment: See also — same question, same data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56333154/how-do-you-return-a-dictionary-through-a-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function, the main change is that I add a `d.update`:

```
def build_book_dict(titles, pages, firsts, lasts, locations):
    inputs = zip(titles, pages, firsts, lasts, locations)
    d = {}
    for titles, pages, firsts, lasts, locations in inputs:
        d.update({
            titles : {
                "Pages" : pages,
                "Author" : {
                    "First" : firsts,
                    "Last" : lasts
                            },
                "Publisher" : {
                    "Location" : locations
                                },
                        },
                })

    return d
```

And now:

```
print(build_book_dict(titles, pages, firsts, lasts, locations))
```

Becomes:

```
{'Harry Potter': {'Pages': 200, 'Author': {'First': 'J.K.', 'Last': 'Rowling'}, 'Publisher': {'Location': 'NYC'}}, 'Fear and Lothing in Las Vegas': {'Pages': 350, 'Author': {'First': 'Hunter', 'Last': 'Thompson'}, 'Publisher': {'Location': 'Aspen'}}}
```

Your code doesn't work because you're creating a new dictionary every time, not adding the dictionaries together, however `d.update` overcomes this issue.

Additionally, I rename the variable `dict` to `d`, since `dict` is a default keyword, whereas when you name a variable of `dict`, you're not able to access the actual `dict` keyword with that.

Answer (score 0):

Create the empty dict before the for loop. And then in the loop add to it like so:

```
def build_book_dict(titles, pages, firsts, lasts, locations):
    inputs = zip(titles, pages, firsts, lasts, locations)
    d = dict()
    for titles, pages, firsts, lasts, locations in inputs:
        d[titles] = {whatever}
    return d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
titles = ["Harry Potter", "Fear and Lothing in Las Vegas"]
pages = [200, 350]
firsts = ["J.K.", "Hunter"]
lasts = ["Rowling", "Thompson"]
locations = ["NYC", "Aspen"]
data = {a:{'Pages':b, 'Author':{'First':c, 'Last':d}, 'Publisher': {'Location': e}} for a, b, c, d, e in zip(titles, pages, firsts, lasts, locations)}
```

Output:

```
{'Harry Potter': {'Pages': 200, 'Author': {'First': 'J.K.', 'Last': 'Rowling'}, 'Publisher': {'Location': 'NYC'}}, 'Fear and Lothing in Las Vegas': {'Pages': 350, 'Author': {'First': 'Hunter', 'Last': 'Thompson'}, 'Publisher': {'Location': 'Aspen'}}}
```